# Add database SET params before query execution in sqlalchemy

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I have a FastAPI app with PostgreSQL database using sqlalchemy to interact with it.

How can I add `SET LOCAL enable_sort = OFF;` before executing any query in sqlalchemy?
Another problem is I'm using 3rd-party packages (e.g. pgvector), which format queries internally.

I tried to add event listener:

```py
@event.listens_for(engine, "before_cursor_execute")
def before_cursor_execute(conn, cursor, statement, parameters, context, executemany):
    conn.execute(text("SET LOCAL enable_sort = OFF;"))
```

however it runs into infinite recursion, since it invokes itself via `execute`.

Comment: If you don't want to set `enable_sort` globally, you could set the configuration when a new transaction is started (since the `SET LOCAL` is scoped to transactions): https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/events.html#sqlalchemy.events.ConnectionEvents.begin